# Дизайн класса Product C#

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Суть программы.
 1. Соединение с сервером, получения списка текущих версий неких продуктов
 2. Сравнение полученных данных с хранящимеся в БД
 3. Вывод различий

Класс Product - содержит id продукта и его наименование
Класс ProductContent (список) - id продукта которому принадлежит, disc - описание контента, href - ссылка для скачивания
Класс Versions (список) - id продукта которому принадлежит, VersionType - тип версии, Ver - номер версии.

Слой для работы с БД на данный момент принимает все эти классы раздельно и пишет их в необходимые таблицы.
Вроде все выглядит довольно достойно, но возник вопрос для удобства работы эти классы необходимо неким образом объединить, первое что пришло в голову сделать так
что бы класс Product содержал в себе экземпляры ProductContent и Versions, т.к. это было бы удобно для сравнения различий между данными с сервера и данными БД, но тогда пришлось бы переписывать компонент работы с БД. Следующий вариант был в компонент где производится получение данных с сервера и последующая сверка с хранящимеся данными ввести класс ну к примеру FullProduct и в нем уже внедрить ProductContent и Versions + в этом же компоненте прописать его получение\сохранение из БД. Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с чем-то подобным?

Answer (score 1):

Что вы имеете под понятиями: "Слой для работы с БД"? "Компонент работы с БД"? Что вы действительно используете?

Попробуйте реализовать на основе **EF CodeFirst**: создать и связать между собой ваши классы, а затем сопоставить с хранилищем данных, ссылка на [пример](http://blog.vkuznetsov.ru/posts/2011/06/12/poshagovyj-obzor-strategii-code-first-v-entity-framework-41#.Ue7j4NKSLto):

```
public class Category
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Архитектурой заложено - отдельный проект для работы с БД. Где прописаны методы сохранения и извлечения данных из БД SQL. Этот компонент оперирует классами Product, ProductContent, Versions раздельно без привязки их друг к другу. Посылаем в него Product - записывает данные в таблицу Products итд. В проекте где идет получение данных и их сравнение сами по себе эти классы не используются, т.е. на этом уровне продукт предст. уже как совокупность этих классов. Единственное что пришло в голову создать AdvancedProduct : Product и уже в этом классе создавать экземпляры ProductContent и  Versions.

Comment: То, что вы описываете — паттерн _Repository_. Вы вполне можете сделать ваши entity-классы (`Product`, `Content`, ...) на EF (например, Code First, как предлагается выше) — это имплементирует для вас связь с таблицами и зависимости, — и написать сверху обёртку (собственно, Repository), которая и предоставит необходимую функциональность вашего модуля.

Comment: Да, быстрая реализация была бы c созданием классов(CodeFirst) - это тот код который выше + обертка + одна строчка LINQ для получения набора различающихся значений. Но правильная реализация в готовом и используемом решении - это дополнить существующий репозиторий новым методом а не городить новый огород. Или обновлять код написанием нового репозитория применяя концепцию CodeFirst.